# What is the difference between onOpen and other functions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to sync timezones between a script and a google sheet. First, i get the timezones of both. Now I have the exact same code in a function onOpen and myCode. onOpen is executed when the sheet opens. myCode I have to execute manually.

The script is it the sheet file, not standalone.

onOpen is not working. In the Log I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: getActiveSpreadsheet is not defined
    at onOpen(Code:2:15)
```

here the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  let sheet = getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log(sheet);
  let sheetTimeZone = getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  Logger.log(sheetTimeZone);
}
```

myCode is working and I get the timezone back.

```
function myCode() {
  let sheet = getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log(sheet);
  let sheetTimeZone = getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  Logger.log(sheetTimeZone);
}
```

I guess, the code onOpen is executed too early. But I can't find any solution or documentation on this issue.

Comment: What is `getActiveSpreadsheet()` of `let sheet = getActiveSpreadsheet();`?

Comment: getActiveSpreadsheet() returns the name of the spreadsheet and stores it in the variable "sheet".
The code itself is working -  but not onOpen().

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying of `getActiveSpreadsheet() returns the name of the spreadsheet and stores it in the variable "sheet".` and your scripts in your question, I cannot image the script of `getActiveSpreadsheet()`. I apologize for this. Because I thought that when `getActiveSpreadsheet()` returns the sheet name, `getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` occurs an error. So, can you provide the script of `getActiveSpreadsheet()`? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike.Please be aware that the script itself is working if the name of the function is "myCode". It is not working when it is named "onOpen".

Comment: Sorry Mario, you are wrong. You can copy/past this code. `getActiveSpreadsheet´ is from google, see here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app
You can create a blank sheet and insert myCode, and it works... with onOpen, it doen't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Based on your comments I think you have confused the differences between classes and methods (functions).

[getActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet) is indeed a built in function **but** it is a method of the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class.

What does that mean?

In order to execute a method of a class in `JavaScript` but also in many other programming languages too you need to call the name of the class and then the function (or method):

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

**Solution:**

In your case, the final result would be:

```
function onOpen() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log(spreadsheet);
  let spreadsheetTimeZone = spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  Logger.log(spreadsheetTimeZone);
}
```

**Bonus info:**

- [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet) **does not** return a [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object but a [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object. This is important because each object has different methods that are available.
- So it is better if you rename variable `sheet` to `spreadsheet` to make clear that distinction. Although the naming of the variables is up to you, it is important to understand the differences between spreadsheets and sheets.
- [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) trigger function runs automatically (is triggered) when a user opens a spreadsheet that they have permission to edit